# datatype that will hold 1000+ characters for Oracle?

Tags: oracle, asp-classic, ado

I have a classic ASP front-end and an Oracle back-end. I'm looking for an **ado datatype** comparable to a `varchar(max)`; it must be **Oracle compatible** and it must hold a 1000 characters.

`advariant` is not an option - the database keeps throwing up when we try to pass such datatype ergo the need for a replacement.

Comment: Do you get any error when using `advariant`?

Comment: I've removed [asp.net] tag and added [asp-classic] tag since you said you're using ASP classic.

Comment: Doesn't using adVarChar passing the quantity in the fourth parameter work for you? `objCommand.Parameters.Append objCommand.CreateParameter("param", 200, 1, 1000, varParam)`